# Workflow with multiple files using a REPL (Python)

Tags: python, emacs

My general workflow is using 2 screens; 1 for the script, 1 for the interactive buffer. I then evaluate parts of the script code in the interactive buffer. This is really nice when working with a small project (I just reevaluate the code I changed at that moment, everything else equal). It allows for (I'm convinced) the fastest iterations in writing a script.

However, I'm now working on a project where I try to be neat and organize my project with a single class per file (or close to it).

Now here lies the issue: While it is easy to evaluate parts of code, in Python it is difficult to import modules once they have already been imported.

Mind that I most of the time have useful objects in the interactive buffer / global scope (perhaps some objects took 10 minutes to be built). This means that I can't just close & reopen everything.

Are others struggling with this as well? How to conveniently work with multiple files and a Python REPL?

Comment: Are you using [importlib.reload(module)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) to reimport modules from REPL?

Comment: I had that in mind yes. Two issues with it. 1) It is a very inconvenient method to run, hard to bind to something like control-enter that would work in any case and 2) Imagine using a particular module script where you might have written some new/test code on the bottom. When you save the file (which is required for the reload), you might have some unexpected effect as well

Comment: when I open more than one file in python, I usually open a dedicated shell for each of them. In principle if no python shell is running, with C-c C-c in a python file should launch a python shell, asking you if you want to open a dedicated process for the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the brilliant [`elpy`](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) package allows this from the latest release (available on MELPA).

You can assign a dedicated REPL to each script as you like. It helps to rename the REPL sessions using <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>rename-buffer</kbd>.

Here is a snippet from [the relevant documentation](http://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#command-elpy-shell-toggle-dedicated-shell):

> ## <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>elpy-shell-toggle-dedicated-shell</kbd>
>
> By default, python buffers are all attached to a same python shell (that lies in the *Python* buffer), meaning that all buffers and code
>   fragments will be send to this shell.
>   elpy-shell-toggle-dedicated-shell attaches a dedicated python shell
>   (not shared with the other python buffers) to the current python
>   buffer. To make this the default behavior (like the deprecated option
>   elpy-dedicated-shells did), use the following snippet:
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook (lambda () (elpy-shell-toggle-dedicated-shell 1)))
> ```
>
> ## <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>elpy-shell-set-local-shell</kbd>
>
> Attach the current python buffer to a specific python shell (whose name is asked with completion). You can use this function to have one
>   python shell per project, with:
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook (lambda () (elpy-shell-set-local-shell elpy-project-root)))
> ```

Here is [the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/pull/1232), which was merged into the master branch on 16th Feb 2018.